# mouse cursor disappears flex/flash ui on mac safari

Tags: apache-flex, macos, safari, cursor

the issue we are facing is that the mouse cursor disappears when a user is using the app in a safari on MAC. The app UI is in flex 4actionscript running in the flash player.

So whenever the cursor hovers over an HDividedBox draggable divider the cursor changes and on returning to the advanced data grid it disappears.

We thought of replacing that with a custom cursor written in javascript, which would have been worked, but we also have  an iframe embedded in the flash movie.

The custom javascript cursor listens for mousemove in the parent div holding the swf and updates its position however the JS script is not usable as the user hovers over an iframe and it does not bubble up the mouse move event.

Looking for an alternate solution now.

Comment: Javascript cursor sounds like a un-maintainable option. What's the wmode used to embed the flash object?

Comment: Are you using native cursors or the old way of doing it with Mouse.hide?  Show the code?  I wouldn't use js if I were you.

Comment: @J_A_X we are still on flex sdk 4.1

Comment: @kunal. do you have the same problem if you try another wmode?

Comment: You shouldn't use wmode transparent.